# Nuxt - $root.$children[0].config is null in Nuxt whereas $root.$children[0].config contains data in VUejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am converting a Vue app to Nuxt app. There is an element in the app which contains the config. But the same in Nuxt contains null. I have tried many ways to search the location of config in Nuxt but have been impossible. Can someone please help?

https://github.com/ProcessMaker/screen-builder/issues/680

Comment: Relying on $children seems like an anti-pattern. Have you tried using another way to store+ access the config, e.g. Vuex?

Comment: Yes tried $refs. Now it works fine.